# Fields are Nots accommodating in the same page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I am trying to create a registration Page which should contain 
First Name,
Last Name,
Gender,
User Name,
Password,
Email,
Blood Group,
Address,
Dob

When I am trying to create these list, All the Field are not accommodated in the same page
[image]

I was able to accommodate only till Email.The rest of the fields(i.e Blood Group,Address,Dob) are not getting accommodated in the same page. How to add those extra field in the same page?
The code for the Layout page is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First Name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/efname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Last Name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/elname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rgender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gender"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/runame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User Name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/reuname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rpass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/repass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eemail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

         <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/submit"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: are you not able to scroll ? Since you've used a scrollview.

Comment: I am able to scroll my page but not able add those extra fields which i have mentioned

Comment: when I am trying to add extra fields,The already existing fields are getting overlapped.I wanted to know how I can accommodate as many fields as required without any overlap.Please suggest something

Comment: Why not just add these after the email edittext ?

Comment: @user3736518 Can you tell me where do you add Blood Group, Address, Dob codes?

Comment: If I add any extra Field in the xml file i.e if I add a text view after email edit text, the app stops running.

Comment: @Hariharan I want to add it immediately after email edit text in the xml file.But I am not able to do so

Comment: @user3736518 Stops running means app crashes. Please edit your question add that fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You views are overlapping because you are putting them inside your RelativeLayout. If you put them just above the relative layout they won't. Added some sample fields :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="First Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/efname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Address"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/elname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rgender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Gender"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/runame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reuname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rpass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/repass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eemail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Blood Group"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eemail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eemail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Blood Group"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eemail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/submit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="Submit" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/submit"
                android:text="Cancel" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

Here, I have put button outside of scroll. I think put submit and cancel button inside scroll view is not convenient way to show layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="First Name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/efname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true">
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Last Name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/elname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rgender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Gender"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/runame"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="User Name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reuname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rpass"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Password"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/repass"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/eemail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```